# Splitting a file records into fix number records

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am having a big file having 10,000 rows, I have to call an API for those records, but only 100 rows can be used at a time, so need to pass 100 rows at a time to that restapi and it needs to be done on scala only.

Comment: so what do you want us to help? you don't even show any code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You'll need to clarify the question, and show what you've tried so far. This question is too broad. Please [read this before posting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

10k records usually is not considered a big data (if each record is under one Megabyte).

Is using Spark a requirement? Spark is a framework for massive parallel distributed computation, and from your description it seems that you want to call API sequentially. In Spark this most probably would've required [loading data into central (driver) node](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#toLocalIterator()) and calling your API from here.

I suggest you to consider processing your data locally. Calling API is not a CPU intensive operation, so there is no need to introduce unnecessary complexity.

Something simple like this would work just as well:

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.Try

val s = Source.fromFile("/path/to/file")

try {
  s.getLines().grouped(100).map {
    ls: Seq[String] => apiCall(ls)  // ls is Seq of 100 lines
  }
} finally {
  Try(s.close())
}
```

If you want to make API calls in parallel instead of in sequence, then you can just use [Scala's built-in parallel collections](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html), as easy as this:

```
  s.getLines().grouped(100).toStream.par.map {
    ls: Seq[String] => apiCall(ls)
  }.seq
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Aivean..have one more doubt,if total lines is not multiple of 100..like suppose I have 198 lines in the file then how it can be handled

Comment: @A.Mishra, in this case, the last batch returned by [grouped](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Seq.html#grouped(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]) will less than 100 elements.